# awk to merge lines based on column

Tags: awk

Would like to merge the lines based on first column `$1` into row and formatted the output. While printing the header need to generate `Max Unique count of first field.`
For example, Angola appears count=3 , Brazil appears count=5 , Zambia appears count=1 . 
Max unique count of field $1 is 5 , so need to print the header 5 times to have a proper header for all the fields.

While print the output, want to keep the `original input file` line Orders.
My actual input files used to be vary like 10 fields, 12 fields etc.

Input.csv

```
Country,Network,Details,Amount
Angola,voda,xxx,10
Angola,at&t,xxx,20
Angola,mtn,xxx,30
Brazil,voda,yyy,40
Brazil,voda,yyy,50
Brazil,at&t,yyy,60
Brazil,mtn,yyy,70
Brazil,voda,yyy,80
Zambia,tcl,zzz,90
```

Desired Output.csv

```
Country,Network,Details,Amount,Country,Network,Details,Amount,Country,Network,Details,Amount,Country,Network,Details,Amount,Country,Network,Details,Amount
Angola,voda,xxx,10,Angola,at&t,xxx,20,Angola,mtn,xxx,30
Brazil,voda,yyy,40,Brazil,voda,yyy,50,Brazil,at&t,yyy,60,Brazil,mtn,yyy,70,Brazil,voda,yyy,80
Zambia,tcl,zzz,90
```

Presently , I am using the below two commands to get the desired output and changing the count manually each time based on number of fields in the actual input file.

Step:#1

```
awk 'BEGIN { while (count++<5) header=header "Country,Network,Details,Amount,"; print header }' > output.csv
```

Step:#2

```
awk -F, '
    /.+/{
        if (!($1 in Val)) { Key[++i] = $1; }
        Val[$1] = Val[$1]  $0 ",";
    }
    END{
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            print(Val[Key[j]] );
        }
    }' input.csv >> output.csv
```

Looking for your suggestions ...

Comment: you can keep an array like `OrderNum[$1]++` and add that as an outer loop to drive your END print statement, but why not just use `awk '{existing prog}' | sort` (as your input data seems to be sorted by country name) ? Good luck.

Comment: And ... pluse uno for a well written Q with small sample data, required output and ... gasp, some very close code! Keep posting and Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` One-liner :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==1{n=$0;next}{a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS:"")$0; if(!($1 in b)){o[++i]=$1}; b[$1]++; mx=mx>b[$1]?mx:b[$1] }END{for(i=1; i<=mx; i++)printf("%s%s",n,i==mx?RS:OFS); for(i=1; i in o; i++)print a[o[i]]}' infile
```

**Input:**

```
$ cat infile
Country,Network,Details,Amount
Angola,voda,xxx,10
Angola,at&t,xxx,20
Angola,mtn,xxx,30
Brazil,voda,yyy,40
Brazil,voda,yyy,50
Brazil,at&t,yyy,60
Brazil,mtn,yyy,70
Brazil,voda,yyy,80
Zambia,tcl,zzz,90
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==1{n=$0;next}{a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS:"")$0; if(!($1 in b)){o[++i]=$1}; b[$1]++; mx=mx>b[$1]?mx:b[$1] }END{for(i=1; i<=mx; i++)printf("%s%s",n,i==mx?RS:OFS); for(i=1; i in o; i++)print a[o[i]]}' infile
Country,Network,Details,Amount,Country,Network,Details,Amount,Country,Network,Details,Amount,Country,Network,Details,Amount,Country,Network,Details,Amount
Angola,voda,xxx,10,Angola,at&t,xxx,20,Angola,mtn,xxx,30
Brazil,voda,yyy,40,Brazil,voda,yyy,50,Brazil,at&t,yyy,60,Brazil,mtn,yyy,70,Brazil,voda,yyy,80
Zambia,tcl,zzz,90
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{
            FS=OFS=","
     }
     FNR==1{
            n=$0;
            next
     }
     {
           a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS:"")$0;
           if(!($1 in b)){ o[++i]=$1 }; 
           b[$1]++; 
           mx=mx>b[$1]?mx:b[$1] 
     }
    END{
           for(i=1; i<=mx; i++)
               printf("%s%s",n,i==mx?RS:OFS); 

            for(i=1; i in o; i++)
                print a[o[i]]
     }' infile
```

**For comment :**

> Would like to know, where to change the code, to print "Country" in
>   the Output only first time , if I don't need to print the same country
>   name 2nd time , third time

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==1{n=$0;next}{a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS substr($0,index($0,",")+1) : $0); if(!($1 in b)){o[++i]=$1}; b[$1]++; mx=mx>b[$1]?mx:b[$1] }END{for(i=1; i<=mx; i++)printf("%s%s",i==1?n:substr(n,index(n,",")+1),i==mx?RS:OFS); for(i=1; i in o; i++)print a[o[i]]}' infile
Country,Network,Details,Amount,Network,Details,Amount,Network,Details,Amount,Network,Details,Amount,Network,Details,Amount
Angola,voda,xxx,10,at&t,xxx,20,mtn,xxx,30
Brazil,voda,yyy,40,voda,yyy,50,at&t,yyy,60,mtn,yyy,70,voda,yyy,80
Zambia,tcl,zzz,90
```

**Modified-code:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{
            FS=OFS=","
     }
     FNR==1{
            n=$0;
            next
     }
     {
           # this line modified
           # look for char pos of comma, 

           a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS substr($0,index($0,",")+1) : $0);

           if(!($1 in b)){ o[++i]=$1 }; 

           b[$1]++; 
           mx=mx>b[$1]?mx:b[$1] 
     }
    END{
           for(i=1; i<=mx; i++)
              # this line modified
              printf("%s%s",i==1?n:substr(n,index(n,",")+1),i==mx?RS:OFS);

            for(i=1; i in o; i++)
                print a[o[i]]
     }' infile
```

**Explanation related to modification:**

- `index(in, find)`

> Search the string in for the first occurrence of the string find, and
>   return the position in characters where that occurrence begins in the
>   string in.

- `substr(string, start [, length ])`

  > Return a length-character-long substring of string, starting at
  >   character number start.

Comment: Would like to know, where to change the code, to print "Country"  in the Output only first time , if I don't need to print the same country name 2nd time , third time

Comment: Wow Great Akshay Hegde , Keep Rocks