# Sort and format lines

Tags: bash, sh

I have the following lines:

```
a;http://example.com/
b;http://qwerty.com/
a;http://example2.com/
c;http://example2.com/
c;http://example2.com/
a;http://example3.com/
b;http://qwerty.com/
b;http://qwerty3.com/
c;http://qwerty.com/
c;http://example5.com/
```

and want to get the following format out of this:

```
a;http://example.com/,http://example2.com/,http://example3.com/
b;http://qwerty.com/,http://qwerty3.com/
c;http://example2.com/,http://example5.com/,http://qwerty.com/
```

but not quite understand how it can be done, the algorithm. Made the following steps:

```
# sort the original list by the first main item; 
output=$(printf "%s" "${output}" | sort -t\; -k1 -n | sort -u)

# split items into two parts
item1=$(printf "%s" "${output}" | cut -d\; -f 1)
item2=$(printf "%s" "${output}" | cut -d\; -f 2)
```

Now there are two parts of the sorted list that can be used to work, but how and in which way to build further logic, I still do not quite understand. It seems that next step is to make some kind of loop and start working with `item1` and `item2` in it.
Can somebody please point to the next steps or give an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716292/using-awk-to-merge-unique-rows-based-on-column-one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592002/awk-to-merge-lines-based-on-column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511500/awk-join-lines-based-on-beginning-or-ending-pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796437/join-lines-with-similar-first-column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
sort -u /tmp/test.list | \
    awk -F';' '
    {
        vect[$1] = vect[$1]","$2
    }
    END {
        OFS=";"
        for (idx in vect) {
            print idx, substr(vect[idx], 2)
        }
    }'
```

You don't care about duplicates, so `sort -u` will help.